# invoking AWS lambda function, wait until completion

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using the following nodeJS lambda function to invoke a java lambda function.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
   
    var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({httpOptions:{timeout: 300000}});
    
    exports.handler = function(event, context) {
      var params = {
          
        FunctionName: 'sensi', // the lambda function we are going to invoke
        InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
        Payload: '{"input":"alum_ROW,10,-1"}',
        LogType:'Tail'
      };
    
      lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          context.fail(err);
        } else {
          context.succeed(data.LogResult);
        }
      })
    };
```

The execution of the caller lambda is successful and the function I am calling is getting executed correctly. The problem is the caller lambda ends before the called lambda function ends and I got `null` as `data.payload` and hexadecimal characters as `data.LogResult`. obviously what is needed is to wait until the called lambda is finished.

below the lambda i am trying to call:

```
public boolean run(String input ){

        String [] inputs= input.split(",");

        String systemId=inputs[0];
        int iterations=Integer.parseInt(inputs[1]);
        int output=Integer.parseInt(inputs[2]);

       //custom code

       return true;
    }
```

This function is inside class `Launchers.Launcher` and therefore the `sensi` lambda function has handler `Launchers.Launcher::run`

EDIT: SOLUTION PROVIDED BY @JOHN

adding: context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling your question, (correct me if I'm wrong and I'll edit the answer):

1. You have a lambda X, that calls lambda Y.
2. Lambda Y returns some value Z for each execution.
3. You want lambda X to receive the value Z, when calling lambda Y.

   1. You want the callback to be called with the return value Z, **after** lambda Y ends execution.

According to your `params`:

1. You request a `synchronous` execution, by specifying `RequestResponse`, which is good for this purpose (receiving the result of lambda Y).
2. You request the last `4KB` of logs produced by lambda Y - by specifying `Tail`.

According to the documentation and given I was right in compiling your question, the `LogResult` is not what you're looking for, but the `Payload` is.

The following is from the **Response Elements** section:

> LogResult
>
> It is the base64-encoded logs for the Lambda function
>   invocation. This is present only if the invocation type is
>   `RequestResponse` and the logs were requested.
>
> The response returns the following as the HTTP body.

---

> Payload
>
> It is the JSON representation of the object returned by the
>   Lambda function. This is present only if the invocation type is
>   `RequestResponse`.

[API_Invoke Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html)

---

### Edit (added example):

I've created two lambdas, according to my above description, X and Y.

**Here's X's code:**

```
let aws = require('aws-sdk');
let lambda = new aws.Lambda();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    const params = {
        FunctionName: "Y", 
        InvocationType: "RequestResponse", 
        LogType: "Tail", 
        Payload: '{"name":"jonathan"}'
    };

    lambda.invoke(params, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        }

        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));

        callback(null, res.Payload);
    });
};
```

**Here's Y's code:**

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event));

    setTimeout(() => {
       callback(null, "My name is Jonathan"); 
    }, 1000 * 10); // 10 seconds delay
};
```

- What you're trying to achieve is do-able.
- Lambda X invokes synchronously Lambda Y and waits for its response (waits 10 seconds).
- **You were accessing the wrong property of the callback input**, you accessed the `LogResult` property instead of the `Payload` property.

Here's a log of X's arbitrary execution:

```
START RequestId: a6a98e8d-31b9-11e7-aba1-d5d86092115f Version: $LATEST
2017-05-05T17:38:40.805Z    a6a98e8d-31b9-11e7-aba1-d5d86092115f    {"StatusCode":200,"LogResult":"U1RBUlQgUmVxdWVzdElkOiBhNzVmMjIzZi0zMWI5LTExZTctYmRmYy0xMzJkMDc0Zjc3YzggVmVyc2lvbjogJExBVEVTVAoyMDE3LTA1LTA1VDE3OjM4OjMwLjY4NloJYTc1ZjIyM2YtMzFiOS0xMWU3LWJkZmMtMTMyZDA3NGY3N2M4CXsibmFtZSI6ImpvbmF0aGFuIn0KRU5EIFJlcXVlc3RJZDogYTc1ZjIyM2YtMzFiOS0xMWU3LWJkZmMtMTMyZDA3NGY3N2M4ClJFUE9SVCBSZXF1ZXN0SWQ6IGE3NWYyMjNmLTMxYjktMTFlNy1iZGZjLTEzMmQwNzRmNzdjOAlEdXJhdGlvbjogMTAwMjcuMjkgbXMJQmlsbGVkIER1cmF0aW9uOiAxMDEwMCBtcyAJTWVtb3J5IFNpemU6IDEyOCBNQglNYXggTWVtb3J5IFVzZWQ6IDE3IE1CCQo=","Payload":"\"My name is Jonathan\""}
END RequestId: a6a98e8d-31b9-11e7-aba1-d5d86092115f
REPORT RequestId: a6a98e8d-31b9-11e7-aba1-d5d86092115f  Duration: 11233.34 ms   Billed Duration: 11300 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 30 MB
```

Note the structure of the callback's input:

```
{
  "StatusCode": 200,

  // this is the logs that Y's printed to the "console" (base64 encoded)
  "LogResult": "U1RBUlQgUmVxdWVzdElkOiBhNzVmMjIzZi0zMWI5LTExZTctYmRmYy0xMzJkMDc0Zjc3YzggVmVyc2lvbjogJExBVEVTVAoyMDE3LTA1LTA1VDE3OjM4OjMwLjY4NloJYTc1ZjIyM2YtMzFiOS0xMWU3LWJkZmMtMTMyZDA3NGY3N2M4CXsibmFtZSI6ImpvbmF0aGFuIn0KRU5EIFJlcXVlc3RJZDogYTc1ZjIyM2YtMzFiOS0xMWU3LWJkZmMtMTMyZDA3NGY3N2M4ClJFUE9SVCBSZXF1ZXN0SWQ6IGE3NWYyMjNmLTMxYjktMTFlNy1iZGZjLTEzMmQwNzRmNzdjOAlEdXJhdGlvbjogMTAwMjcuMjkgbXMJQmlsbGVkIER1cmF0aW9uOiAxMDEwMCBtcyAJTWVtb3J5IFNpemU6IDEyOCBNQglNYXggTWVtb3J5IFVzZWQ6IDE3IE1CCQo=",


  "Payload": "\"My name is Jonathan\"" // <--- this is the returned value
}
```

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: thanks @johni, you are correct. the problem is that  return type should not be null, it should be "true" which is returned by Y. the caller lambda X is done way before the the Y lambda is finished.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you referring, where did I say it should be null?

Comment: am just saying that X get currently null from Y. but it should not because Y returns true.

Comment: Ah I see your point. Well, in the answer I tried to explain that you were looking at the wrong place - the LogResult property holds the traces your lambda outputs, not the return value - for that you should use the data.Payload property.

Comment: and the other problem is that X execute the invoke callback very soon, it does not wait for Y to finish execution. maybe that is why it is getting null

Comment: yes the data.Payload i tried it and it is null. when i am referring to null i mean data.Payload

Comment: You use RequestResponse - so it should wait for Y to finish. Looking at Y's code - it shouldn't take long to run.

Comment: well in Y you see i commented //custom code. this custom code takes 15 sec to finish. i am doing statistics here. but X looks 3 sec to finish

Comment: I see. Well what you're describing is not consistent with the documentation. I'll test it myself soon and get back to you on that.

Comment: @FrancoisSaab no.

Comment: @FrancoisSaab btw if this edit answered your question I would appreciate you accepting it.

Comment: Thank you i just added this and it worked: context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;